# mvc: Custom client validation using model parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, custom-validators

I am trying to implement a custom client validation for a textbox field. I have a model that looks like

```
public class mymodel{
   public string str1{get; set;}
   public string str2{get; set;}
   public string str3{get; set;}
}
```

I want to add a custom validation on str3 that uses the value from str1 and str2. something like `if(str1.equals(str2)) then value of str3 = ...`
 A generic custom validation method looks like this.

```
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
   public override bool IsValid(object value)
   {

    return true;
   }
}
```

Is is possible to pass in extra parameters to this method? And how will the declaration of the validation on the property look like. Or is there an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the model

```
public override bool IsValid(string str)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return false;
        }           

        if (this.str1 == str)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```